# Where to find Tactical Exercises on the Decoy

Tags: tactics, problems

A decoy tactic is forcing an enemy piece to move to a square that prevents it from guarding an original square.

For example, if the black queen is at c7 and the f7 square is being attacked, getting the queen to move to c6 would be a successful decoy tactic.

Where can I find such puzzles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paid version of chesstempo allows you to search the problem database for all kinds of [tactical motifs](https://chesstempo.com/tactical-motifs.html). Depending on your exact definition of "decoy tactic", you should look for what they call "attraction", "distraction", "clearance", "coercion", "sacrifice" and perhaps more.

Comment: Great, but how do I search for "attraction" tactics? I see Attraction under the Tactical Motifs link, but I only see a description and not a list.

Comment: @JossieCalderon: Under search, but as I wrote, this works only if you paid for a chesstempo premium account.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.amazon.com/365-Ways-Checkmate-Joe-Gallagher/dp/1901983951](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1901983951)

It has lots of mind blowing tactics inside, including decoys. I finished it in one year and it caused an huge leap in my tactical ability.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very good one. Make sure you pause the video when you are prompted to do so. Try to find the decoy tactic yourself: https://youtu.be/Ib05HINpMsI